# Firebase addListenerForSingleValueEvent download usage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm pretty new in Firebase.

I have read that Firebase have few method to listen changes on database, `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` and `addValueEventListener`.

I know that `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` only get data once, so this method only use download quota once per call.
What about `addValueEventListener`? It listens for changes in database all the time. With this method listening all the time, how is the download quota used? I mean does this method keep using the download quota or just when there are changes then download quota will be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are charged for the JSON size of any data sent from Firebase's servers to a connected client. So if you attach a listener that retrieves the initial data, and then gets one update, you will be charged for that initial data, and for the update that were sent.

The Firebase client and server work together to minimize the amount of data that needs to be downloaded, so the updates may be smaller than the total size of the JSON data that you attach a listener to.

The best way to get a feeling for the amount of data that the Firebase server sends to a client, is by [enabling debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and checking the logcat output of your app. It will show something pretty close to the wire traffic for Firebase, which is a good indication of the actual data size transferred.

---

In addition to the JSON data size, you're also charged for the bandwidth used in setting up an SSL connection. Especially on mobile clients (where apps tend to be used for relatively short intervals) this overhead is a significant factor on the bandwidth used.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Can you clarify how does the optimization works? I'm particularly curious about this case scenario: Let's say a *partial* update was made on a node that a listener is attached to (for e.g, the node has 100 children but only 1 of them was updated). Will the whole node be fetched again to the client, or just the updated child? Or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: It does a delta-sync based on hashes of the current local branch and the remote data for that branch. If you search my previous answers for delta-sync, you'll probably find a longer explanation.